# Gson - Get generic SerializedName

Tags: java, gson

```
public class MyClass{
    @SerializedName("hello")
    private String hello;

    @SerializedName("world")
    private String world

    @SerializedName("dynamic")
    private String dynamic;
}
```

I want to be able to parse all dynamic* names to the variable dynamic.
Example:

> {"hello":"hello", "world":"world", "dynamic123":"qwerty"}
>
> {"hello":"hello", "world":"world", "dynamic345":"asdfgh"}
>
> {"hello":"hello", "world":"world", "dynamic567":"zxcvbn"}

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom Gson Deserilizer for your MyClass

```
public class MyClassDeSerializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyClass> {
    @Override
    public MyClass deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> property : jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
            if (property.getKey().contains("dynamic")) {
                myClass.setDynamic(property.getValue().getAsString());
            }
            else if (property.equals("hello")) {
                myClass.setHello(property.getValue().getAsString());
            }
            else if (property.getKey().equals("world")) {
                myClass.setWorld(property.getValue().getAsString());
            }
        }
        return myClass;
    }
}
```

And Create Gson by registering this Class

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(MyClass.class , new MyClassDeSerializer()).create();
```

Deserilize

```
MyClass result = gson.fromJson(json, MyClass.class);
```